# shell script to process data from two input files

Tags: linux, shell

I have a lot of fastq files for ~100 samples (two per samples: reads1 and reads2). For each sample, I need to input the two fastq files into Prinseq, a perl program. Ideally, this would be great to do with a shell script for all samples so I don't have to manually call this program 100 times, but I don't know how to indicate two input files, just one (i.e., for i in *.fastq; do [perl commands]; done). If it helps, Prinseq command format is as follows:

> perl prinseq-lite.pl -fastq [file for reads1] -fastq2 [file for
>   reads2] -derep [options]

This is probably a very easy answer, but I can't find it.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you show what the manual calls would look like?

Comment: the perl command example is how the manual calls would be. If you are looking for an example of how the input files themselves are formatted: `Hypselonotini_Anasa_bellator_CMF_0316_S74_L005_R1_001.fastq`  `Hypselonotini_Anasa_bellator_CMF_0316_S74_L005_R2_001.fastq` `Acanthocorini_Acanthocoris_scaber_CMF_0177_S61_L005_R1_001.fastq` `Acanthocorini_Acanthocoris_scaber_CMF_0177_S61_L005_R2_001.fastq`

Comment: I just want a script that assigns R1 and R2 of each species to the `-fastq` and `-fastq2` arguments.

Comment: Do all the R1 files end with `R1_001.fastq`?

Comment: yes and it's the same for `R2_001.fastq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all `R1` files and use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to chop off the `R1_001.fastq` part (and replace it by the `R2` version):

```
for i in *_R1_001.fastq; do
    perl prinseq-lite.pl -fastq "$i" -fastq2 "${i%R1_001.fastq}R2_001.fastq"
done
```